# Filter String with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

Hi i need filter a string with a regular expresion. I have read that I must use the method Replace of the class Regex with a pattern but I don't know that Expresion Regular I need to filter my String.
I have a large string s and I want extract or filter the ? in the next pattern of the string:
"string fixed?_IP"
string fixed is a string that always is the same
IP is a valid IP number

Please I need the pattern to pass to the function Replace of the class Regex to obtain the string ?

I try some patterns but anyone works.

```
pattern1="(ftp_files\\?_[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)"
pattern2= "(ftp_files\\?_/^(([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]).){3}([1-9]?[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/)"
```

ftp_files\ is the string fixed

In pattern2 I try an expresion regular that I have found to validate an IP.

Comment: Please show us *which* patterns you've tried.

Comment: I edit my post with two patterns I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `Regex.Replace` if what you want is to extract the information. You have to call `Regex.Match` for that. Or, if you really want to call `Replace`, please tell us what part you want to replace, and what should the substitute look like.

```
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"ftp_files\\\?_(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)");
var ipAddress = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
```

Here I chose a more legible regex for the ip address (`\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+`). If you really need to ensure each byte of the IP is valid, you could replace each instance of `\d+` in that expression with something like this: `(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)`.

---

EDIT: If you want to extract what's between `ftp_files\` and `_IP`, here's the regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(inputString, @"ftp_files\\(?<value>.*?)_(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)");
var value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want extract the IP I want extract the text between ftp_files\ and _IP and this solution is for extract the IP.

Comment: Thanks for your outstanfing help. I have tried your code and it works. I don't handle much the regular expresions and I have been stuck for hours with these problem.

Comment: @JoseM. You're welcome. Break this expression down looking at the [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) trying to understand it. Regex is a great tool once you master it.